# Convert array data model to dictionary (swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, datamodel

**Data Model**

```
class DataCart {
   var icon: UIImage?
   var cartId: String
   var price: Int
   var productName: String
   var quantity: Int


init(icon: UIImage?, cartId: String, price: Int, productName: String, quantity: Int){
    self.icon = icon
    self.cartId = cartId
    self.price = price
    self.productName = productName
    self.quantity = quantity

  }
}
```

**Dictionary**

```
var cart = [DataCart]()

"products": [[
    "productName": "Photobook", //"dataCart.productName"
    "quantity": 2,   //"dataCart.quantity"
    "price": "5000.00",  //"dataCart.price"
    "pages": 40
    ],[
    "productName": "Photobook2",
    "quantity": 5,
    "price": "7000.00",
    "pages": 30
    ]]

for dataCart in cart {
........
}
```

I've array from data model that i'd like to show it as dictionary, and i got confused to change it. How to convert cart's array (DataCart) to dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    var allDictionaries : [[String : AnyObject]]//array of all dictionaries.

    func convertArrayToDictionaries([DataCart]) {
       for data in DataCart {
          let  dictionary = [
             "icon" : data.icon,
             "cartId" : data.cartId,
             "price" : data.price,
             "productName" : data.productName,
             "quantity" : data.quantity
          ]
          allDictionaries.append(dictionary)
       }
 }
```

Comment: why it shows 'type of  expression is ambiguous without more context' in let dictionary line? @NSGangster

Comment: its all good now, just add [String : AnyObject] to let dictionary. thank you btw!

Answer (score 4):

**It's good practice to make conversion at class level.**

**So in future if you have more keys, you just need to change at class level only instead of changing in all the places where you have used the same.**

Add one calculated property `dictionayDataCart` in class as below.
Also add one method "`convertDataCartArrayToProductsDictionary:`" which will convert your array of objects to dictionary.

```
 class DataCart {
        var icon: UIImage?
        var cartId: String
        var price: Int
        var productName: String
        var quantity: Int


        init(icon: UIImage?, cartId: String, price: Int, productName: String, quantity: Int){
            self.icon = icon
            self.cartId = cartId
            self.price = price
            self.productName = productName
            self.quantity = quantity

        }

        var dictionaryDataCart : [String : AnyObject] {

            var objDict : [String : AnyObject]!

            if let icon = self.icon {
                objDict["icon"] = icon;
            }

            objDict["cartId"] = self.cartId;
            objDict["price"] = price;
            objDict["productName"] = productName;
            objDict["quantity"] = quantity;

            return objDict;
        }

        class func convertDataCartArrayToProductsDictionary(arrayDataCart : [DataCart]) -> Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
            var arrayDataCartDictionaries : Array<Dictionary<String,AnyObject>> = Array()
            for objDataCart in arrayDataCart {
                arrayDataCartDictionaries.append(objDataCart.dictionary);
            }
            return ["products" : arrayDataCartDictionaries];
        }

        }
```

**Use method as below.**

```
let arrayDataCarts : [DataCart] = //value of your array
//pass it to class function and you will get your result

let productsDict = let productsDict = DataCart.convertDataCartArrayToProductsDictionary(arrayDataCarts);
```